# How do I ask the user if he wants to use the program again?

Tags: python

```py
import math 

print('Enter the coefficients:')

a = float(input('a = '))
b = float(input('b = '))
c = float(input('c = '))
D = b ** 2 - 4 * a * c

if D > 0:
 print('The discriminant is greater than zero, the expression has 2 roots:')
 print('x1 =', (-b + math.sqrt(D)) / 2 * a)
 print('x2 =', (-b - math.sqrt(D)) / 2 * a)

if D == 0:
 print('The discriminant is 0, the expression has 1 root:')
    print('x =', -b / 2 * a)

if D < 0:
    print('The discriminant is negative, there are no roots')
```

Comment: Put all the code inside a `while True:` loop. At the end, ask if they want to play again, and `break` if they say no.

Comment: You should use `elif` and `else:` for mutually exclusive conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `while True` and then check if the user wants to continue using the program with an `input()` call:

```
import math

keep_looping = True
# Keep looping until user inputs anything other than yes or y
while keep_looping:

  print('Enter the coefficients:')
  a = float(input('a = '))
  b = float(input('b = '))
  c = float(input('c = '))
  D = b ** 2 - 4 * a * c
  if D > 0:
    print('The discriminant is greater than zero, the expression has 2 roots:')

    print('x1 =', (-b + math.sqrt(D)) / 2 * a)

    print('x2 =', (-b - math.sqrt(D)) / 2 * a)
  elif D == 0:
    print('The discriminant is 0, the expression has 1 root:')
    print('x =', -b / 2 * a)

  elif D < 0:
    print('The discriminant is negative, there are no roots')

  # Check if user wants to continue
  response = input("Do you want to continue using the program?")

  # I chose to check for yes and y, but you can add what you want here.
  if response.lower() != 'yes' or response.lower() != 'y':
    keep_looping = False
```